# Windows 8 resetting permissions

Tags: windows-8, file-permissions, iis

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate machine that was upgraded to Windows 8 Pro.  There's a recurring issue that's preventing IIS from serving a folder tree.  After some experimentation, I think I found the underlying issue, but need help understanding what's causing this.

I have a folder off the root of one of my computer's drives that's set to not inherit permissions.  I set it to give the user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' read access.  I can confirm the changes take effect, as IIS then is able to serve the contents of this folder and its subfolders.

When I reboot, the IIS user's rights are removed from the folder.  The same happens if I try granting access to the IUSR user or IIS_IUSRS group instead.  IIS is no longer able to access the folder.  What's causing this?  It started after upgrading to Windows 8.

I tried to audit permissions changes to see if I could track the change.  I followed [this guide](http://windowsitpro.com/security/auditing-permission-changes-folder), and found no Event ID 560 entries in my Event Log.  But the IIS Apppool user is still getting removed on reboot.

**Answers to some questions :**

```
1. Are you serving this website on the internet or on an Intranet?
```

Intranet, users access it simply by going to `http://computername/`.

```
2. Are you connected to a Windows Domain?
```

Nope.

```
3. Have you tried adding the IUSR account to the folder permissions?
```

Yes, same result.

```
4. Is this site being hosted as a virtual folder or an application?
```

I don't believe it's configured as either a Virtual Folder or Application. The site is the Default Web Site. I configured it so its Physical Path is the base folder of this folder tree. When I click 'View Applications' or 'View Virtual Directories', I'm presented with an empty list.

```
5. What if you change the permissions, then boot into Safe Mode?
```

This seems to prevent the issue from recurring.  When I boot into Safe Mode, the issue doesn't recur, the changed permissions stay changed.  However, upon booting back into non-Safe Mode, the issue recurs.

Comment: This is likely because of a change in the version of IIS that is now used by Windows 8.  Verify your using the same version as you were using I would put money down on the fact there not the same.

Comment: @Ramhound Umm, I'm using the version that's built in to Windows.  The errors I'm getting have an HTML page title of 'IIS 8 <something>', so AFAIK, I'm now on IIS 8.

Comment: I know your using IIS 8, so were you using IIS 8 before when it was working, if so then some change between IIS 7.5 and IIS 8 is the cause.  You will need to use virtual machines to determine the cause of this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound `It started after upgrading to Windows 8.`  AFAIK, IIS should be irrelevant to the issue of folder permissions changing.  I only included it to be thorough in case it was relevant.  Unless you can point me to some documentation that shows that IIS is known to change permissions?

Comment: I always give the permissions to the `IIS_IUSRS` account and it works perfectly well (although never done it in Win8). Sub-folders should be set to inherit. Consider giving the "Read & execute" permission in addition to "Read".

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the tip, but that group got removed from the folder's ACL after a reboot too.

Comment: If the accounts were not translated well from Win7 to 8, the only easy solution is a reformat and clean install of 8. Or of course returning to Win7 (which frankly seems much more stable).

Comment: So, a few questions: 1. Are you serving this website on the internet or on an Intranet? 2. Are you connected to a Windows Domain? 3. Have you tried adding the IUSR account to the folder permissions instead of AppPool\Default App Pool? 4. Is this site being hosted as a virtual folder or an application?

Comment: 1. Intranet, users access it simply by going to `http://computername/`.  2. Nope.  3. Yes, same result.  Upon reboot, IUSR is removed from the folder. 4. I don't believe it's configured as either a Virtual Folder or Application.  The site is the Default Web Site.  I configured it so its Physical Path is the base folder of this folder tree.  When I click 'View Applications' or 'View Virtual Directories', I'm presented with an empty list.

Comment: @pnuts I have been doing so.  No one has pointed out how IIS' configuration would be remotely relevant, so I haven't added those details.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode after adding these permissions?

Comment: @harrymc Safe Mode does seem to prevent the permissions from reverting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say that this problem does not happen when booting in Safe mode, then this is not
a problem with Windows, so it is some installed product that plays with the permissions.

Use for example [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to turn off startups in bunches to find out which one is responsible for it. I would start with security products such as suites, then Explorer add-ons and so on.